# Operating system not found

Tags: installation, 13.04

I have uninstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and installed Ubuntu 13.04 instead. It told me that Ubuntu is installed and that I need to restart my PC. After restarting I got an error message that said: `operating system not found`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot using the live CD and install Boot Repair program:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

then launch Boot Repair, use the default settings and follow the instructions (it may ask you to do something manually)